# Convertir RGB a HSV

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy usando JAVA y ANDROID, e logrado extraer el RGB de un pixel al 255: "RGB:115-25-39", y por paginas web de conversión me arroja en HSV 351°-78%-45%.

*PROBLEMA: El problema va al convertir H no me arroja el 351 ni como para restar 359°-H°=351°; como lo corrijo o de que otra forma puedo obtener el HSV.

*S y V si se convierten bien.

Dejo mi codigo:

```
    DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    DecimalFormat formato1 = new DecimalFormat("0");


    //Luminocidad / Brillo
    /double L=((MaxRGB+MinRGB)/2);
    //txtviewcolor1.setText( "La luminosidad es de: "+formato.format(L*100) + "%");

    //HSV
    //V=MaxRGB
    double  V = MaxRGB;
    double  H = 0;
    double  S = 0;

    //S
    if (MaxRGB== 0) {
        S=0;
    } else {
        S=(MaxRGB - MinRGB)/MaxRGB;
    }


    //H
    if(MaxRGB==MinRGB){
        H=0;
    } else {
        if (MaxRGB == (r/255)) {
            if((g/255) < (b/255)){
                H = (((g/255) - (b/255)) / (MaxRGB - MinRGB)) + 6;
            }else {
                H = (((g/255) - (b/255)) / (MaxRGB - MinRGB)) + 0;
            }
        } else if (MaxRGB == (g/255)) {
            H = (((b/255) - (r/255)) / (MaxRGB - MinRGB)) + 2;
        } else if (MaxRGB == (b/255)) {
            H = (((r/255) - (g/255)) / (MaxRGB - MinRGB)) + 4;
        }
    }

    txtviewcolor2.setText( "H"+formato.format(H/6)+ " - S"+formato1.format(S*100)+ " - V"+formato1.format(V*100));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas calculando mal `H`, sin embargo, en java ya existe el método `RGBtoHSB` de la clase `Color` que realiza esta converción.

Ejemplo utilizando el `RGB` que das como ejemplo:

```
   // Enviando RGB:115-25-39
   int r = 115;
   int g = 25;
   int b = 39;
   float[] hsv = new float[3];
   hsv= Color.RGBtoHSB(r, g, b, hsv);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hsv));
   hsv[0]*=360;
   hsv[1]*=100;
   hsv[2]*=100;
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hsv));
```

La salida de este programa es:

```
[0.97407407, 0.7826087, 0.4509804]
[350.66666, 78.26087, 45.098038]
```

Comment: EL RGBtoHSB me marca de rojo, tengo que añadir alaguna libreria ?

Comment: No debería marcarte error, pero puedes importar "import java.awt.Color" por si acaso.